# Making Mastermind in Python

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am simply wondering how I can make my game of Mastermind work, more specifically how I would go about making "finish" global, how I would call these functions so that the program works correctly, and overall tips that would help enhance my code. I would also like to know how to make it so the program doesn't 'reroll' the computer-generated number every single loop. This was just a difficult problem for me and I can't seem to understand how to close it out with the correct function calls and niche aspects such as that. Thank you.

````
run = True

def get_guess():
    while run:
        guess = input("Provide four unique numbers: ")
        count = 0
        if len(guess) == 4:    
            guessdupe = guess[0] == guess[1] or guess[0] == guess[2] or guess[0] == guess[3] or guess[1] == guess[2] or guess[1] == guess[3] or guess[2] == guess[3]
        else:
            guessdupe = False
        try:
            try:    
                for i in range(4):
                    if int(guess[i]) <= 7 and int(guess[i]) >= 1 and len(guess) == 4:
                        count += 1
                if len(guess) != 4:
                    print "Your guess must consist of 4 numbers!"
                if guessdupe:
                    count -= 1
                    print "You can only use each number once!"
            except ValueError:
                print "You can only use numbers 1-7 as guesses"
        except IndexError:
            print "You can only use numbers 1-7 as guesses"
        if count == 4:
            break
    return guess

def check_values(computer_list, user_list):
    final_list = [''] * 4
    for i in range(4):    
        if user_list[i] in computer_list:
            if user_list[i] == computer_list[i]:
                final_list[i] = "RED"
            else:
                final_list[i] = "WHITE"
        else:
            final_list[i] = "BLACK"
    random.shuffle(final_list)
    print final_list
    return final_list



def check_win(response_list):
    if response_list[0] == "RED" and response_list[1] == "RED" and response_list[2] == "RED" and response_list[3] == "RED":
        print "Congratulations! You've won the game!"
        global finish
        finish = True



def create_comp_list():
    while run:
        compList = [random.randint(1, 7), random.randint(1, 7), random.randint(1, 7), random.randint(1, 7)] 
        listBool = compList[0] == compList[1] or compList[0] == compList[2] or compList[0] == compList[3] or compList[1] == compList[2] or compList[1] == compList[3] or compList[2] == compList[3]
        if listBool:
            continue
        else:
            return compList



def play_game():
    for i in range(5):
        print create_comp_list()
        print get_guess()
        check_win(check_values(create_comp_list(), get_guess()))
        if finish:
            break


play_game()```
````